# Mouse movement % based but mouse still goes flying where it's not supposed to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, mouse, pyautogui

I need some help badly. I got all my mouse movement simulation in % so it can work for other resolutions like this:

`win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int((300/1920)*width), int((-50/1080)*height))`

Which is meant to make it move 300 pixels to the right and 50 pixels up and it works perfectly on my computer, however, people are trying to use my program, the mouse moves way too far away for some reason and it isn't going to the proper spot.

What could be the issue and what do I need to do to fix.

EDIT: Found the issue. I don't have "enhance mouse precision" in windows while they do, it essentially gives mouse acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I don't have "enhance mouse precision" in windows while they do, it essentially gives mouse acceleration.